# Is Meta SE the place to send positive feedback regarding StackExchange engine?

Tags: discussion, meta

I feel the need to send positive feedback regarding one of SE's engine's "new" features: *Review Feedback as Comment*.

Is Meta SE the site to post such a comment/question?  If not, how should I proceed?

NOTE: 
I believe that such a comment could be phrased as a question "Does Review Feedback as Comment mark a shift to a more transparent SE?", for example.  But would that be cheating?

Comment: You're a good soul, tony gil.  Positive feedback is incredibly motivating for us (and most people who work on things they care about).

Comment: @Jaydles being called a "good soul" made my week on monday.  tks, m8!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To send positive feed back the best solution is to find the post that announced this change and vote it up.

If you want to articulate *why* you liked it, how it may help you more than folks realize, or which aspect was important to you, adding a comment to that effect is a good way to convey more info, and hopefully drive more work like that in the future.

In this case the question was posted on Meta Stack Overflow:

[Add indication that canned comments are from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829/add-indication-that-canned-comments-are-from-review)

So unfortunately you're going to have to search in more than one place :(

Comment: any idea how i do that?  I did try to find said post, but i believe that i might not even be looking in the right place.

Comment: @tonygil Generally, if you search MSO and MSE, you'll be covered. Most features that are engine wide will be on MSO, but sometimes there are grey areas or something ends up on MSO because it was based on a lot of existing input and discussion that started there.

Answer (score 7):

Even on Meta, it is still Q&A. So if you have no question, not an answer to add to the original post, it is best to leave it and just up-vote the corresponding post.

Sometimes these 'new feature' meta posts have the ability to answer with your feedback. Make sure it is more than just a 'yes, this is good' answer if you do. Explain what it adds according to you, where it helps and where it might fail (a [good example on the original post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272063/993547) here from Kate). Such post should have added value over the original post. If not, the up-vote button is your friend.

Comment: totally agree, that is why i refrained from placing my feedback as a cleverly phrased question, even if i could reasonably expect to have a fair chance of "getting away with it".  :)

Comment: It is good you came here!

Comment: thank YOU for taking the time to help me (and maybe even others)